# How to prevent component from re-rendering in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The content component and it takes the API as a argument from another component. But when it takes a new input and the API updates it re-renders(i think twise) and the result array is empty. That is the problem.
Here is the code.

```
    import React from 'react';
import  { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const Content=(api)=>{

  const [cities, setItems] = useState([]);

  const API=api;
  console.log(API);

  
  useEffect(() => {
  //  setItems([]);  //clearing cities array.deleting previuos data from the array
    fetch(API)
      .then(res => res.json(console.log(res)))
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(cities)
          setItems(cities => cities.concat(result));
          
        },
      )
  },[API]);

  console.log(cities)

    return (
        <ul>
        {cities.map(citi => (
          <li key={citi.city.id}>
            The city is is{citi.city.id} 
            The city name is{citi.city.name}
            The temparature is {citi.list[0].main.temp}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
  
      
    )
  }


export default Content;
```

The first log is returning an empty array.
But the second log is returning the array with correct results
Here is the console [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA52L.png)

As you can see it renders twice and the final array is an empty one. So my issue is that the final result array is an empty array even id the api is fetching data. Because of that this component is not returning anything. How to fix that. The output is showing that the array is empty

please don't downvote.Just leave a comment if this needs an improvement

Comment: "As you can see " no we can't, this is not a [mcve] so you'll want to fix that. Also, why are you not using `setItems(cities.concat(result))`? The `setItems` function already updates `cities` with whatever you pass in it, because that's how the `useState` hook works, why the arrow function?

Comment: @gmoniava,   the problem is that the final array is empty. so the component returning nothing. i wanted the final array not to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the API you have mentioned here is props and it should be props.api. The answer is using the api in the Content component after destructuring from props

```
import React from 'react';
import  { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const Content=({api})=>{

  const [cities, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(api){
        fetch(api)
           .then(res => res.json())
           .then(result => {
                // add some guarding condition here for result
                let updatedCities = cities.concat(result);
                setItems(updatedCities);
           })
    }
  },[api]);

  console.log(cities)

    return (
        <ul>
        {cities.map(citi => (
          <li key={citi.city.id}>
            The city is is{citi.city.id} 
            The city name is{citi.city.name}
            The temparature is {citi.list[0].main.temp}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>     
    )
  }
export default Content;
```

This would only re-render when the API has changed.